# Debian 10: Checking the Status of Services

Tags: debian, logs, services, daemon, systemctl

I want to know if it is possible when checking the status of a service on the system with `systemctl status application.service,` see the full log lines, not only the first few log lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask [`systemctl`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html) not to shorten unit names, journal lines etc. with `--full`, and specify a larger number of lines with `-n`:

```
systemctl status --full -n 1000 ...
```